# Enforce a specific load order of imported modules

Tags: python, python-import, circular-dependency

*See **Background** below for a motivation on why I don't think restructuring the code is a good solution.*

Let's imagine I have three modules with the following contents (the structure of the code in the codebase I encountered this problem is much more complicated and moving the code around slightly does not work):

```
# myapp/a.py
from . import b, c

class A:
    def to_b(self): return b.B()
    def to_c(self): return c.C()
```

```
# myapp/b.py
from . import a

class B(a.A): pass
```

```
# myapp/c.py
from . import a

class C(a.A): pass
```

This does not work. Regardless of which of these modules I try to import, I get an error:

```
cs ~/test$ python3.6 -c 'import myapp.a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "myapp/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import b, c
  File "myapp/b.py", line 3, in <module>
    class B(a.A): pass
AttributeError: module 'myapp.a' has no attribute 'A'
```

The modules are not loaded in the order necessary for this to work. `A` needs to be fully loaded before `B` and `C` can be loaded. If we change `myapp/b.py`'s `import` statement to `from . import c, a` this is achieved and it works.

But this feels like I'm tricking the runtime into doing what I want instead of declaring it in the form intended by the language designers. Removing or adding an import in the wrong place can lead to an error that is almost un-diagnosable by someone who does not have a very deep understanding of the issues at play here (mind you, I'm facing this issue not with 3, but with about 20 files and I had to deal with even larger, tangled import graphs in the past).

Another trick is to move the `import` statement in `myapp/a.py` to the bottom of the file. This, again, feels like a hack and is equally brittle when imports are added or removed.

I'm aware that the `import` statement could also be moved into the functions, but this has some runtime cost and requires `lambda` expressions to be converted to functions.

My question: What is the intended way to enforce the required module load order in a situation like this? Extra points if it does not feel like a hack and happens in a single or few places so that it can be easily documented.

#### Background

This problem came up when working on a large-ish Django project, specifically when splitting its `models.py` (2.5 k lines/80 classes) into multiple more manageable files (about 20). My question is unrelated to Django or ORMs in general. But the way Django database models are declared lends itself to this issue.

For those not familiar with, models (≈ database tables) are declared using Python classes, foreign keys using references to the other class objects. See this abbreviated example from the [documentation of Dango's ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/):

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    [...]

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
```

This means that classes need to be declared in a specific order as references are processed while the class body is run.

The model of the project I'm working on is big and complicated and so we added a lot of helper functions to the model classes, many of which access other models. E.g.:

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    def get_albums(self):
        return Album.objects.filter(artist=self)
```

(The actual queries are usually much bigger, hence we want to abstract them)

This example works without issues because class `Album` will have been defined when `Musician.get_albums()` is called.

Now imagine we want to move `Musician` and `Album` into separate files. `Musician` depends on `Album` and `Album` depends on `Musician`, requiring a circular import.

Now I could move `get_albums()` into its separate, third file, but that would place two related and intertwined pieces of code into separate files and change the API exported by `Models`. I don't think that's a good solution because the placement of the function was not an issue when all model definitions were in a single file.

This is the basis of the problem I described above, in a simplified situation.

Comment: For the record, in the end I went for option number "move `import` statements into functions". IMHO, it's the least confusing option.